# What do the (site, here, up) arguments mean when creating rocket-chip configurations?

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

When creating a new "Config" we define a function that takes three "View"s (site, here, up) as arguments.  What is the meaning of these three Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As purely a historical reference, take a look at the [Chisel2 Advanced Parameterization Manual](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs250/fa14/handouts/parameters.pdf) (with the huge caveat to not take this too literally as it's old). However, I believe that the motivation and discussion of `site`, `here`, and `up` still holds in sections 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, and 3.6.

Roughly, `site`, `here`, and `up` help with handling and resolving dependencies on other parameters.

`site` allows you to disambiguate different parameters that may have the same name, e.g., `Width`, based on a defined location. `here` allows parameters to query other parameters defined in the same group. `up` allows you to access a parent configuration's parameter object with the intended purpose being if you want to copy it while modifying parameters.

Comment: That document is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: That link is dead :( Can someone tell me where I can find it?

Comment: Sorry! The link should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Blah extends Config ((site, here, up)) {..}
```

is the parameter tuple, which allows partial function application. This allows partial configuration of the Rocket core and setting default parameters, preserving elasticity and type correctness.

You may check its implementation [here](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/blob/840d2a2226319c50fc6d0d7bd1186c00dd8df511/src/main/scala/config/Config.scala#L47)

Comment: I've looked through the implementation.  I don't understand why three views are used rather than a single view.  In the rocket-chip repository I can see lots of examples where "site" is getting used, a couple of examples where "up" is getting used and no examples of where "here" is getting used.  Presumably there's a reason that three parameter sets are being used, rather than just one.

Comment: Perhaps, that's a design artifact from an early life of Rocket. It's being under active development for about 5 years, so you may open a Pull Request and improve/refactor this, if you feel it is an important feature

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the purpose.  I thought maybe they related to global versus local module level parameters or something like that.